# getText() toString() method not working on method parameters

Tags: java, android, tostring

After I introduce inputs (Strings, example: A, B etc) on EditText fields in my android application, and I pressed the button my application stops. I'm new in android applications. I get the null pointer exception, when I'm trying to invoke a method **"on a null object reference"** but I don't understand why my object is null...
If I write the values in variable

```
weight = Main.callMethod("A", "B");
```

it works perfectly, but if i let the values from the application like in the line

```
weight = Main.callMethod(source, destination);
```

the application stops.

Here are the 2 classes I used:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button b;
public static EditText currentLoc, selectDestination;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    currentLoc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    selectDestination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // this.tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    currentLoc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //tv.setText(s);
            source = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    selectDestination.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //tv.setText(s);
            destination = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    //source = currentLoc.getText().toString(); //getHint() instead og getText()
    //destination = selectDestination.getText().toString();

    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button

            int weight; //= 0;

            Log.d("Source", "Current loc:" + source + " END");
            Log.d("Destination", "Select destination:" + destination + " END");

            Log.d("Compare", "2 strings " + source.equals("A"));

            Log.d("Source length" ,"is: " + source.length());
            Log.d("Destination length", "is: " + destination.length());

            //weight = Main.callMethod("A", "B");
            weight = Main.callMethod(source, destination); //not working !!!
            tv.setText("" + weight);

            //tv.setText("Your Input: \n" + source + "\n" + destination + "\nEnd.");
        }
    });
}
```

}

And the method from the other class is this:

```
public class Main {

public static int callMethod (String source, String destination) {

    List<Path> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Path("A", "C", 4));
    list.add(new Path("A", "B", 6));
    list.add(new Path("B", "C", 2));
    list.add(new Path("B", "D", 2));
    list.add(new Path("C", "D", 1));
    list.add(new Path("C", "E", 2));
    list.add(new Path("E", "D", 1));
    list.add(new Path("E", "F", 3));
    list.add(new Path("D", "F", 7));

    DijkstraAlgorithm object = new DijkstraAlgorithm(list);
    list = object.compute(source, destination);

    int weight = 0;
    for (Path path : list) {

        weight = path.getWeight();
        //System.out.println(path.getSource() + " -> " + path.getDestination() + " (" + path.getWeight() + ")");
    }

    return weight;
}
}
```

The Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.nicoleta.trafficappfinal.Pair.getSource()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.nicoleta.trafficappfinal.DijkstraAlgorithm.generateShortestPath(DijkstraAlgorithm.java:112)
                                                                                      at com.example.nicoleta.trafficappfinal.DijkstraAlgorithm.compute(DijkstraAlgorithm.java:28)
                                                                                      at com.example.nicoleta.trafficappfinal.Main.callMethod(Main.java:45)
                                                                                      at com.example.nicoleta.trafficappfinal.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22651)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

**DijkstraAlgorithm** - in this class the problem seems to be, Path, Pair classes:
**EDIT:**

```
public class DijkstraAlgorithm {
private final List<Path> graph;
private List<Path> shortestPath;
private Map distance;

public DijkstraAlgorithm(List<Path> graph)
{
    this.graph = graph;
}

public List<Path> compute(String start, String end)
{
    List<Path> list = new ArrayList();
    list.addAll(graph);
    shortestPath = new ArrayList();
    distance = new HashMap();
    distance.put(start, new Pair(0, "\0"));
    compute(start, end, list);
    generateShortestPath(start, end);

    return shortestPath;
}

private void compute(String source, String destination, List<Path> graph)
{
    Path bestPath = null;

    for (Path path : graph)
    {
        if (path.getSource() == source)
        {
            int pathVal = path.getWeight() + ((Pair) distance.get(source)).getValue();

            if (!distance.containsKey(path.getDestination()))
            {
                distance.put(path.getDestination(), new Pair(pathVal, path.getSource()));
            }
            else
            {
                if (((Pair) distance.get(path.getDestination())).getValue() > pathVal)
                {
                    distance.remove(path.getDestination());
                    distance.put(path.getDestination(), new Pair(pathVal, path.getSource()));
                }
            }

            if (bestPath == null)
            {
                bestPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                if (((Pair) distance.get(bestPath.getDestination())).getValue() > ((Pair) distance.get(path.getDestination())).getValue())
                {
                    bestPath = path;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    List<Path> remove = new ArrayList();

    for (Path path : graph)
    {
        if (path.getSource() == source || path.getDestination() == source)
        {
            remove.add(path);
        }
    }

    graph.removeAll(remove);

    if (bestPath != null)
    {
        if (bestPath.getDestination() != destination)
        {
            boolean check = false;

            for (Path path : graph)
            {
                if (path.getSource() == bestPath.getDestination())
                {
                    check = true;
                }
            }

            if (check)
            {
                compute(bestPath.getDestination(), destination, graph);
            }
            else if (!graph.isEmpty())
            {
                compute(graph.get(0).getSource(), destination, graph);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void generateShortestPath(String start, String end)
{
    Pair pair = (Pair) distance.get(end);

    Log.d("Start", "is " + start); //this is now visible
    Log.d("End", "is " + end); //this is also visible
    Log.d("Msg1", "is " + "source " + pair.getSource() +   //at this line is the error !!!
                                    " value " + pair.getValue() +"\n");

    shortestPath.add(new Path(pair.getSource(), end, pair.getValue())); 

    while (pair.getSource() != start)
    {
        String c = pair.getSource();
        pair = (Pair) distance.get(pair.getSource());
        shortestPath.add(new Path(pair.getSource(), c, pair.getValue()));
    }

    Collections.reverse(shortestPath);
}
}



public class Pair {
private int value;
private String source;

public Pair(int value, String source)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.source = source;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public String getSource()
{
    return source;
}

public void setValue(int value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public void setSource(String source)
{
    this.source = source;
}
}


public class Path {
private String source;
private String destination;
private int weight;

public Path(String source, String destination, int weight)
{
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getSource()
{
    return source;
}

public String getDestination()
{
    return destination;
}

public int getWeight()
{
    return weight;
}

public void setSource(String source)
{
    this.source = source;
}

public void setDestination(String destination)
{
    this.destination = destination;
}

public void setWeight(int weight)
{
    this.weight = weight;
}
}
```

Comment: what values do `source` and `destination` have?

Comment: Please, share your stack trace

Comment: post the error of logcat..

Comment: Provide your logcat

Comment: Strings @luk2302

Comment: You need to reproduce when your app crash and share the logcat that provided by android studio in that moment

Comment: Provide your logcat with errors bro

Comment: @Heisen-Berg I posted a photo now

Comment: @rockar06 here it is now

Comment: Scroll to right then post a pic. Or just copy-paste your error.

Comment: copy and paste it. dont post a photo of it. its missing key infomration. but right away, its throwing a null pointer. its being thrown in your Dij class. can you post that along with the pasted error.

Comment: Its better if you copy and paste the logcat, we can't see the error in the photo

Comment: And it could be better if you share your Dijk... class

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.nicoleta.trafficappfinal.Pair.getSource()' on a null object reference whats in the getSource() in your pair?

Comment: inside of generateShortestPath, the path.getSource is null. thats why it isnt working.... its your job to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `EditTexts` `currentLoc` and `selectDestination` are not `final`. And initialize them outside of the `button.setOnClickListener()` that means, initialize them after the statament

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

or more before.

And always check that if the`length` of `source` and `destinition` is more than `0` distinctly, before the statement

```
weight = Main.callMethod(source, destination);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is the problem! The length of source and destination are always 0. Hope I figure out why.

Comment: Did you declared currentLoc and selectDestination as final? If they are final, then no new value will be set with them.

Comment: No no, they are not final (only public static), and I've moved the initialization as you said.

Comment: Can the .xml file be the problem?

Comment: I solved the lenght 0 problem. The problem is stll in code line 112.

Comment: Now my strings start and end are visible in generateShortestPath but I still get the null pointer exception...